# Moving physical windows 7 to Hyper - V on windows 2008 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, hyper-v

I have a Windows 7 on a PC, but I want to install Windows 2008 R2 on the computer. I also want to keep Windows 7 on as a VM.

Can I use disk2vhd?
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx

Can I create a windows & full backup and restore it on Hyper-V?

Please let me know what will work best and if you have any other suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using Disk2VHD will allow you to create a VM from your physical machine, you can create this, move the image off the machine, install server 2008 R2 and Hyper-V role, then import the Windows 7 VHD.